# MS Access 2016 connection related

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to access an .accdb from HTML code. The code is as follows and it stops executing at 
 var cnn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

Not clear as to what is wrong with the code..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Reality company details</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<p> Hi here 1111111 .. connection ... done </p> ");
      var pad = "C:\\Users\\Uma\\Documents\\SampleDB.accdb";
      document.write("<p> Hi here 2222222 .. pad set.. done </p> ");

      var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source=" + pad;
      document.write("<p> Hi here 3333 .. connection ... done </p> ");
      var cnn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
      document.write("<p> Hi here 444444 .. connection ... done </p> ");
      var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

      cnn.Open(strConn);
      var SQL = "SELECT * FROM RealityTable";    
      rs.Open(SQL, cnn);
      if(!rs.bof) {
        rs.MoveFirst();
        if(!rs.eof) {
         document.write("<p><br>" + rs.fields(1).value + ", ");
         document.write("<br>" + rs.fields(2).value + ", ");
         document.write("<br>" + rs.fields(3).value + ".</p>");
         }
      }
      else {
        document.write("No data found");
      };
      rs.Close();
      cnn.Close();

      </script>

      </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you followed [Microsoft's manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/jscript-code-example-to-return-a-recordset)?

Comment: The code which gave me that err is there. Any idea why it doesn't run that AcitveXobject()

Comment: From what I can see from the manual I have linked to above, the code needs to be inside a function, and you have to specify at least a few predefined variables like `DB`, `DS` and `DP`. Please try wrapping the code inside a function and employing a try-catch, the way it's done in the code example I have provided. If you could try outputting the error in some way (try-catch is good for that), that would help as well.

Comment: @pyromonk , Found Out that ActiveXobject was blocked on IE 11. Got that fixed and works fine with same code and no changes done to it.

Comment: That's peculiar... Thank you, I didn't know. Could you please submit an answer to your question, so that others would get to know what information you have read and what specific changes you have made? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The IE browser versions from 8 to 11 blocks all activeXobjects. Fixed that is blocking ActiveXobject from running.